# mongo db design for fast queries on ranges

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Currently, I have a mongoDb collection with documents of the following type (~1000 docs):

```
{   _id : "...",
     id : "0000001",
   gaps : [{start:100, end:110}, {start:132, end:166}...], // up to ~1k elems
  bounds: [68, 88, 126, 228...],                           // up to 100 elems
  length: 300,
    seq : "ACCGACCCGAGGACCCCTGAGATG..."
}
```

"gaps" and "bounds" values in the array refer to coordinates in "seq" and "length" refers to "seq" length.
I have defined indexes on "id", "gaps" and "bounds".
I need to query based on coordinates ranges. For example given "from=100" and "to=200" I want to retrieve for each document a sub-array of "gaps", a sub-array of "bounds" and the "seq" substring that lay inside the range (between 100 and 200 in this case).
Right now, this is done using the following aggregation pipeline:

```
    db.annot.aggregate(
         {$match  : {"id" : "000001"}},
         {$unwind : "$gaps"},
         {$unwind : "$bounds"},
         {$match: {
                    $or :[
                         {"gaps.start" : {$gte:from, $lte:to}},
                         {"gaps.end" : {$gte:from, $lte:to}},
                         {"bounds" : {$gte:from, $lte:to}}
                    ]
                  }
         },
         {$project:{
                 id:1,
                 gaps:1,
                 bounds:1,
                 subseq:{$substr:["$seq", from, (to-from)]}}},
         {$group : {
                 _id : "$id",
                 gaps : {"$addToSet" : "$gaps"},
                 bounds : {"$addToSet" : "$bounds"},  
                 subseq : {"$first" : "$subseq"}}},
    )
```

- Querying the whole collection (leaving out the first "$match" in the pipeline) takes ~14 seconds.
- Querying individually all the documents **sequentially** takes at most 50msec each (~19 secs in total).
- Querying individually all the documents **in parallel** takes in total ~7 secs.
- Querying with a pipeline that only matches the id (ie, using the first "$match" in the pipeline) takes ~5 secs in total.

What would be the best db and query design to maximize the performance of this kind of queries?

Comment: What's the relationship between gaps and bounds, if any? The trouble is the double $unwinds, which takes your one document and produces up to 100 * 1000 documents from it, one for every pair (gap, bound). Also, what exactly do you mean by querying sequentially vs. querying in parallel?

Comment: There is no relationship between gaps and bounds. They are both coordinates that refers to the seq field, but they don't have relationship with each other. Yes, I know that the "$unwinds" creates individual documents for each gap/bound pair, this is why I would like to change the document/collection format. And by "sequentially" I mean that I query each document (for example) in a for loop (with the "aggregate" query above) and by "parallel" I mean that I create different threads (as many as cores) and run the queries in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

> *What would be the best db and query design to maximize the performance of this kind of queries?*

Since you ask for improving your code and design, i suggest you to switch to the latest version of `mongodb` if you have not yet. That should be a good starting point. For these type of problems, the basic idea should be to `reduce` the `number of documents` being `input` to each `pipeline operation`.

I suggest you to have a additional variable named `range` which contains all the numbers `between` `from` and `to`, inclusive of both. This allows us to apply functions like `$intersection` on the `bounds` array.

So the variables, the aggregate operation needs from the environment should be:

```
var from = x; var to = y; var range=[x,...,y];
```

- The first step is to match the number of documents that have  the
  `id`,`gaps` sub documents and `bounds` value in our range. This
  reduces the number of documents being input to the next stage to say 500.
- The next step is to `$redact` the **non conforming** gaps sub
  documents. This stage now works on the 500 documents filtered in the
  previous step.
- The third step is to `$project` our fields as our need.

Notice that we have **not** required to use the `$unwind` operator anywhere and achieved the task.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match  : {"id" : "0000001",
            "gaps.start":{$gte:from},
            "gaps.end":{$lte:to},
            "bounds" : {$gte:from, $lte:to}}},
{$redact:{
         $cond:[
                 {$and:[
                        {$gte:[{$ifNull: ["$start", from]},from]},
                        {$lte:[{$ifNull: ["$end", to]},to]}
                       ]},"$$DESCEND","$$PRUNE"
               ]
         }},
{$project: {
            "bounds":{$setIntersection:[range,"$bounds"]},
            "id":1,
            "gaps":1,
            "length":1,
            "subseq":{$substr:["$seq", from, (to-from)]}}}
])
```